# How to render index from Angular project in Node Project

Tags: node.js, angular, express, server-side-rendering

I have two folders into a principal folder, one folder is called frontend, and had the angular project, and the other is called backend, this folder has a backend and all API. I would switch this project like SSR project, can integrate the angular project into a node project, then when I execute

`npm run dev`

And node project starts on the respective port, automatically the frontend side starts within.

I tried multiples ways to create a path from one folder to another, but not have success.

[image: server index.js]

[image: Project structure project]

If I do this

```
const indexTest = (path.join(__dirname, `../frontend/src/index.html`))

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render(indexTest)
})
```

Appear this error

[image: Error res.render]

But, if I do that

```
const indexTest = (path.join(__dirname, `../frontend/src/index.html`))

server.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(indexTest)
})
```

Don't show me any error, but the principal page is blank

[image: blank page]

Server firmware code

[image: firmware]

Server app index.js principal

[image: index server app]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to render the frontend based on the source, and that will not work.
On Angular projects you need to build the code first, so later you can render it.

If you want to do SSR, then you will need to use something like [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Another option would be to point the backend to the `dist` folder, and then run the [angular cli in watch mode](https://angular.io/cli/build) (scroll till bottom). Like this: `ng build --watch --output-path dist`

You will need to add [this code](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) to your backend.

Probably something like this:

```
server.use(express.static('../frontend/dist'))
```

Comment: Thanks, I go to try and tell you back in a moment

Comment: I have this config in the index file into a folder server, https://i.imgur.com/Fy1Skpg.png

Comment: You will need to do something like: server.use(express.static('../frontend/dist'))

Comment: I add the line code, but I don't  know what to do.

Comment: @PedroMiguelPimientaMorales  You need to run the ng build command I left on the answer, it will generate a build and store it on the output path. Then you specify your backend app to serve static content from that very same output path. On the screenshot, you have the wrong path, as the path is relative, you shouldn't remove the `../`.

Then start the backend server (yes, you need both commands running at the same time). Now your backend will serve the frontend files on localhost:3000.

Please put your whole code so I can help you.

Comment: Let me try to understand, I have to move dist folder to the backend folder?, let me try with the path like you say

Comment: If I use the route to access to folder frontend and all files like you said, it's not possible, https://imgur.com/H3mECU9

Comment: Could you tell me, What code exactly do you need, and I edit the question

Comment: Finally work, I was making a mistake, I will, should to use `res.sendFile` instead `res.render`, thanks.